# union of open balls is subset of another union of open balls

Tags: metric-spaces, set-theory

I need help with the following task:
Let $M$ be a metric space and $x_1,...,x_n\in M$ and $r_1\geq r_2\geq...\geq r_n>0$. Show that there exists $I\subseteq\{1,...,n\}$ so that $U_{r_j}(x_j)\cap U_{r_i}(x_i)=\emptyset$ for every $i,j\in I$ with $i\neq j$ and $\bigcup_{j=1}^n U_{r_j}(x_j)\subseteq \bigcup_{i\in I} U_{3r_i}(x_i)$
($U_r(x)$ is the open Ball with center $x$ and radius $r$)
I don't know how to start here. Maybe it is possible to construct $I$ explicitly?
Thanks for any help and hints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is (the finite version of) the  famous Vitali Covering Lemma:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitali_covering_lemma

If you want a proof you can peak at the page! A hint is that the proof is inductive: start with one ball. If it does not do the trick add another! Keep going. The process must terminate.